# circular navigation with wheelnav.js - SVG does not rotate text

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, wheelnav.js

I just started using wheelnav.js in order to build a navigation.

This is the [Spreader](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/documentation/spreader.html) I would like to use (the 2nd example). Interestingly, just this one does not render as in the example. The Text does not rotate.

I just took the code example exactly as it is:

```
wheel = new wheelnav('wheelDiv'); //stored in a var
wheel.spreaderInTitle = 'menu';
wheel.spreaderOutTitle = 'close';
wheel.spreaderTitleFont = '100 24px Helvetica';
wheel.spreaderInPercent = 0.8;
wheel.spreaderOutPercent = 1.1;
wheel.colors = ['#EDC951'];
wheel.spreaderEnable = true;
wheel.spreaderRadius = 85;
wheel.slicePathFunction = slicePath().DonutSlice;
wheel.clickModeRotate = false;
wheel.createWheel(['text', 'icon', 'percent', 'angle', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]);
```

I built a quick demo with both examples from the documentation site, the 1st looks ok the 2nd doesn't: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoffs/8pdmj68L/3/)

EDIT: if I make it bigger e.g. 500px the spacing is better, but still the text is not rotated...

As far as I can see there are no further css rules (?) to apply.. Do I miss something - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the [titleRotateAngle](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/documentation/core.html#sectionProperties) property.

```
wheel.titleRotateAngle = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, now the titles are rendered in the expected angle. Seems I did not explore alls sections of the documentation enough.. The remaining problem now is, if it is initially rendered it looks fine, but when clicking the spreader, the titles disappear with a "strange animation". And when clicking again to show them, they are initially out of angle/rotation and align correctly after the bounce effect stops. I'll post if I found out why..

Comment: You use v2.2.0 of raphael, but wheelnav.js works with v2.1.2. Here is a modified and working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pdmj68L/8/)

Comment: Thanks again - I replaced the raphael file and did not think about compatibility with newer version ^^